# How to fit mixture of gaussians with identical mean?

Tags: density-function, unsupervised-learning, gaussian-mixture-distribution, density-estimation

Say I have data generated by a mixture of gaussians whose components have the same mean, but very different covariances, like the one generated by this code:

```py
X1 = np.random.randn(1000, 2) @ np.array([[6, 0], [0, 1]])
X2 = np.random.randn(1000, 2) @ np.array([[1, 0], [0, 6]])
X = np.vstack([X1, X2])
```

Fitting gaussian mixtures to this data with EM algorithm seems to fail, the model with 2 components getting a worse BIC than models with 1, 3 or 4 components!

Is there a way to fit a mixture of gaussians to this case in order to find the accurate number of components? Of course, the goal would not be to assign each data point to a specific cluster, but rather to model the underlying data pdf by a sum of gaussian pdfs.

Comment: The "ECP" multivariate change-point methods in the `R` `ecp` package are based on a solution to this problem and it seems to work well: see Matteson David S. & Nicholas A. James (2014),  “A Nonparametric Approach for Multiple Change Point Analysis of Multivariate Data,” Journal of the American Statistical Association, 109:505, 334-345, [DOI: 10.1080/01621459.2013.849605.](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.2013.849605)